# cout doesn't work in my code when use c++

Tags: c++

Can anyone help me with this code?I don't know why cout doesn't work and it doesn't show the (i - 1) in line 14;

The question is:
Joe have 240 minute to do his exam.First question need 5 minute time,second question want 10 minute and etc.He need k minutes to eat dinner after exam.Now we want to know how many questions can he do.
n is number of questions and k is the time that takes for eating dinner.

```
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, n, k, sum = 0;
    cin >> n >> k;
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        if(sum <= 240 - k){
            sum += 5 * i;
        }
        else{
            cout << i - 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What input are you using? What is the objective?

Comment: "doesn't work" is too generic. You should describe what is happening actually, and what input are you using.

Comment: for example I use 3 for n and 222 for k @lakeweb

Comment: After `sum += 5 * i;` add `std::cout << sum << std::endl;` and you will see why.

Answer (score 0):

cout is buffered.  `i` probably *does* appear, just not where you're looking: right before the next prompt, because you're not sending a newline.

```
cout << i - 1 << '\n';
```

You may also see:

```
cout << i - 1 << endl;
```

Here, `endl` is a newline plus an instruction.  When inserted into the ostream, if causes a flush, forcing all pending output to be written.  That  can be handy when you need to interleave buffers on one device, as when sending standard input and standard output to the same file or terminal.

Answer (score 0):

because there is case like for n = 5 and k = 10 where `sum` cannot reach the threshold to actually print. i'm not sure about what you want to do but printing  out of the loop might help.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, n, k, sum = 0;
    cin >> n >> k;
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        if(sum <= 240 - k){
            sum += 5 * i;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << i - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that the cout statement is inside the loop's else block. This means it will only be executed when the else condition is met, i.e., when sum exceeds {240 - k}. If the loop completes without reaching this condition, the cout statement will not be executed.

here, is the update version of your code:-

```
  if(sum <= 240 - k){
        sum += 5 * i;
```

Note:- The cout statement is not inside the loop, and it will be executed after the loop has finished